# Retrieving Auto-Generated ID in JDBC

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I'm currently writing code that inserts new values into a relation that has an auto-generated ID.

```
create table person (
person_id   number(5) generated always as identity
            minvalue 1
            maxvalue 99999
            increment by 1 start with 1
            cycle
            cache 10,
firstname   varchar(10) not null,
lastname    varchar(10) not null,
);
```

Then, I'm trying to insert a tuple within Java with JDBC:

```
Statement s;
String query = "insert into PERSON (firstname, lastname) values (\'" + firstname + "\'" + ", " + "\'"
                    + lastname + "\')";
s.executeUpdate(query);
```

This all works fine, but I need to get the generated ID back into my Java program so that I can work with it. Is there any way to do this well?

Thanks!

Comment: please read also about Prepared Statement

Comment: Specifically, use prepared statements to avoid string pasting.

Answer (score 0):

Use the JDBC method `stmt.getGeneratedKeys()`. That will give you back the IDs just generated.

Comment: That in itself is not sufficient to get the generated id. You also need to prepare  / execute the statement in the right way.